# Confusing note regarding Bokeh Autoload Scripts

Tags: javascript, python, html, bokeh

While reading the User Guide for Embedding Bokeh content, specifically "Autoload Scripts" here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#autoload-scripts

The suggestion is to use the `bokeh.embed.autoload_static()` function to generate a `.js` file and a `<script>` tag to embed it into an HTML document.

As the documentation states,

> The script tag should be included in the HTML page wherever you wish to load the plot.

This works as intended. However, there is an additional note that makes no sense to me:

> Note: The `<script>` tag loads a `<div>` in place, so it must be placed under `<head>`.

This seems contradictory to the previous instruction which asks you to place the `<script>` tag where we wish the plot to be loaded, and therefore somewhere under `<body>`. Placing this tag under `<head>` does nothing and does not load the plot at all.

Have I misunderstood this note? What is it actually trying to tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo, it should indeed be `<body>`. I've created https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10484

Comment: Oh wow! Here I was driving myself mad wondering if I was missing something fundamental about HTML.